# Chrome Extension JavaScript Program Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I am learning chrome extension programming from the tutorial [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2013/11/23/chrome-extension-programming/) .

You can find the full code for the chrome extension [here](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/twitteropt.zip).

The code snippet where I tried to remove few links:

```
var clean_twitter = function(){
  var ugly = [];
  ugly.push('.Trends module trends');
  ugly.push('.flex-module');
  ugly.push('.MomentMakerHomeModule-header');
  ugly.push('.Footer module roaming-module');
  ugly.push('.flex-module-header');

  $('.promoted-tweet').hide(); // oops! :P

  for(var i=0;i<ugly.length;i++) {
    var u = $(ugly[i]).find('a'); // also 'b'
    u.text('');
  }
}
```

The code tries to remove some buttons and div from the twitter website.

Now, when I put it on my pc nothing happens. I tried to remove the change link inside the trends box and it isn't removed.

Please help if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the `process_new_tweets` function there's a comment explaining how the presence or absence of `.mini-profile` in the DOM is used as a flag.

In summary, the absence of the `.mini-profile` element in the DOM means that the function returns and won't proceed any further. Since the tutorial was written it would appear that Twitter no longer has a `.mini-profile` element anywhere in its DOM, so the function is always returning and script execution is not proceeding any further.

Remove the following lines from the beginning of the `process_new_tweets` function:

```
var mp = document.getElementsByClassName('mini-profile');
if(mp.length === 0) { return; }
```

And the elements that you've selected in your `clean_twitter` function will be removed from the DOM as expected.